# send JSON or array to submit POST (jQuery -> PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, forms

Good morning.
I'm stucked on this thing:
I'm doing a form (which send info to other page via submit button, post) which dynamically user can add some other form-groups with a button.
Ok, that's easy. 
BUT the user is making something called "DPT" (work stuff) which have a table in my DB, and also have a "Function" (things to do) table. A DPT can have one or many Functions.

```
Function              
---------
id int(4) AI
title VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
description VARCHAR(256)
dpt int(4) --> FK
      | 1..*
      |
      V 1
DPT
-----
id
name
(...)
```

So I have a `<div>` which I inflate with jQuery for making a panel and form inside it.
Why I did that? Because if a DPT  can have one or many Functions I have to store the ID of the current Function I am creating.
Then I have a button for adding more functions, but I have to storage the ID of the function and the title and description of it.

So with jQuery I can dynamically add before the button of "Add function" a new form...
My idea was create a JSON and send it via PHP but have no idea where I have to send  the info or where to return to...

I let you here my important code for doing the thing:

```
<div id="initialFunction" class="panel panel-default panel-body">
<?php 
 $nextID = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(id_funcion) as siguiente_id from funcion"))['siguiente_id'];
?>
 <button class="button btn-danger" type="button">
  <span class="fa fa-minus">
  </span>
 </button>
</div>

<script>

var nextId = <?php echo $nextID?> 
var arrayToPass = {}
$(function(){
    $("#initialFunction").html('<div class="form-group">'+
            '<label>Función a desarrollar <sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>'+
            '<input class="form-control" name="funcion" type="text" placeholder="Función a desarrollar" maxlength="200" required>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<label>Tarea principal en esta función <sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>'+
            '<textarea class="form-control" name="tarea" placeholder="Enumere las funciones de su puesto de trabajo comenzando por las más representativas, así como las tareas necesarias para el cumplimiento de las mismas" rows="3" required></textarea>'+
        '</div>');
});

$("#bttn-add").click(function(){
    $("#bttn-add-function").before(
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<label>Función a desarrollar <sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>'+
            '<input class="form-control" name="funcion" type="text" placeholder="Función a desarrollar" maxlength="200" required>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<label>Tarea principal en esta función <sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>'+
            '<textarea class="form-control" name="tarea" placeholder="Enumere las funciones de su puesto de trabajo comenzando por las más representativas, así como las tareas necesarias para el cumplimiento de las mismas" rows="3" required></textarea>'+
        '</div>');
        nextId++;

});
```

Can I return an array/json when I do click on the submit button and pass it through POST?
something like:

```
$("#guardar_dpt").click(function(){
    return json_object
} )
```

?

I show you a [image: photo] what I am doing.
also the entire form: [image]

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You could also use the shorter form: [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but all the other info are stored in a form. How can I pass the array to the form? With ajax only can send the json, dont? or when I press submit button can I do a Ajax post and send form also?

Comment: @SumanDey some way to send an array/json and the other info of the form too

Comment: You can send what ever data you want with Ajax. It's super easy to post a complete form, specially since you're already using jQuery. Please do some research and read some guides/tutorials about Ajax (there are literally a _ton_ of tutorials for this).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. And simple. Here is example:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first"><br>
  <input type="text" name="last"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
```

JS:

```
function parseAnswer (data) {
  var content

  content += 'Name: ' + data.first + '<br>'
  content += 'Surname: ' + data.last

  $('#output').text(Name)
}

$('#myForm').on( "submit", function (evt) {
  var data = $(this).serialize()

  evt.preventDefault()
  $.post('any.php', data, parseAnswer)
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/json");

  $first = $_POST['first'];
  $last = $_POST['last'];

  $arr = ['first' => $first, 'last' => $last];

  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: that's an approaching what I want. In my PHP I have a query to a DB to insert values and then I must pass from the page the form data and the array I am making. Thanks for posting and helping :)

Comment: I'm trying to add my json array to the data for passing all but get an error as "data.push" is not a function. That's my code:

Comment: `$("form").submit(function(event){
        $(".toadd").each(function(index){
            var array = {}
            array["id"] = $(this).find("input").val()
            array["funcion"] = $(this).find(".func input").val()
            array["tarea"] = $(this).find(".tarea textarea").val()
            console.log(array)
            arrayToPass.funciones.push(array)
        })
        var data = $(this).serialize()
        data.push(arrayToPass);
        console.log(data);
        event.preventDefault();
    })`

Comment: Nevermind, I was using serialize, but I must use serializeArray ;)